# PHPSESSID is changed when I send an Ajax request in Chrome

Tags: php, ajax

I send two requests via Ajax that execute two functions in PHP. First function sets `$_SESSION['data']="data";` and the second one gets its value `$_SESSION['data']`, just simple.

When I send the first request `PHPSESSID` gets a value, but when I send the second request `PHPSESSID` is different. When `PHPSESSID` changes the getter function in PHP fails because `$_SESSION['data']` doesn't exist, it happends because the second request is sent to another PHP session since `PHPSESSID` has another value. **This problem only happends when I use Chrome, but it works with Firefox and Edge, it's so strange.**

Why it happends and how can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

There is an example of the code bellow:

#### HTML file: start.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>    
    function sendSetRequest() {
        let set_params = {
            "action" : "action_set"
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: set_params,
            url: 'functions2.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#cntr_debug").html(result);
            }            
        });     
    }
    
    function sendGetRequest() {
        let get_params = {
            "action" : "action_get"
        };
        $.ajax({
            data: get_params,
            url: 'functions2.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                $("#cntr_debug2").html(result);
            }            
        });
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        sendSetRequest();
        sendGetRequest();
    });
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="cntr_debug"></div>
        <div id="cntr_debug2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### PHP file: functions2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump(session_id());

    function setSession() {
        $_SESSION['data'] = "data";
        return $_SESSION['data'];
    }
    
    function getSession() {
        return $_SESSION['data'];
    }
    
    if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
        $action = $_POST['action'];
        switch($action) {
            case 'action_get' : echo getSession(); break;
            case 'action_set' : echo setSession(); break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're calling `sendGetRequest()` before the response to `sendSetRequest()` has been received, so the cookie isn't set yet.

Comment: @Barmar Then, how can I fix this?

Comment: Call `sendGetRequest` in the success function of `sendSetRequest`

Comment: Or return the promise from `sendSetRequest`, and call `sendGetRequest` in its `.then()` method.

Comment: @Barmar I did it but I get the same problem with Chrome, `PHPSESSID` is different in each call. With Firefox it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for `sendSetRequest()` to finish its AJAX request before you call `sendGetRequest()`, so that the browser will have received the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

You can have `sendSetRequest()` return the `$.ajax()` `Deferred` object, and call `sendGetRequest()` from its `.done()` method.

```js
function sendSetRequest() {
  let set_params = {
    "action": "action_set"
  };
  return $.ajax({
    data: set_params,
    url: 'functions2.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#cntr_debug").html(result);
    }
  });
}

function sendGetRequest() {
  let get_params = {
    "action": "action_get"
  };
  return $.ajax({
    data: get_params,
    url: 'functions2.php',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(result) {
      $("#cntr_debug2").html(result);
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  sendSetRequest().done(function() {
    sendGetRequest();
  });
});
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with this, if I only want to retrieve the value stored in `$_SESSION['data']` in other side of the HTML code I can't apply this solution. I just only want to keep the same `PHPSESSID` in each call using Chrome, because Firefox doesn't change it.

Comment: If you mean the value that was set in some earlier call, then you don't need to call `sendSetRequest()` at all.

Comment: `PHPSESSID` gets its value the the first time any of your pages starts a session. You're only having a problem because your first AJAX call is creating the session. If it was created earlier, you don't need to set a new value, you can just call `sendGetRequest()`.

Answer (score 1):

On the browser side, session is maintained by a session cookie. PHP's session cookie is PHPSESSID.

What you're doing here is hoping that the browser will pick up the cookie after an AJAX response, which may not happen. The best way to be sure is to convert your start.html file to start.php, and start just by starting the session, like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html> ... your code from start.html file
```

Comment: @Briko check if you have PHPSESSID cookie in your browser. If everything is set correctly, it should have the same value as what you get from `session_id()`

Comment: I checked it and I get same values as cookies, but I found something, there is an icon with shape of triangle with an exclamation that says: "this set-cookie was blocked due to user preferences". Can be this the problem?

Comment: Could be. Session relies on cookies for normal function... Check your browser settings, perhaps it's too strict on cookies. I tried the code I proposed and it worked, so there's got to be something off on your browser settings. Try disabling all plugins also

Comment: "Check your browser settings, perhaps it's too strict on cookies". Oh damn, it's that!. I don't know why Chrome is configured to block all cookies, I even don't use Chrome, thanks, thank you very much.